# Directional derivative -- from definition to using unit vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

One of the definitions for a directional derivative of $f$ in direction $v$ is as follows:
$$
\nabla_v f(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+hv) - f(x)}{h\lvert v \rvert}
$$

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), if $f$ is differentiable at $x$,
$$
\nabla_v f(x) = \nabla f(x) \cdot \frac{v}{\lvert v \rvert}.
$$

Why is this the case?

Comment: On this site, you're recommended to type out the equations instead of posting links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then this means that there is a vector $\nabla f(x)$ such that $$f(x + u) = f(x) + u\cdot \nabla f(x) + o(|u|)$$ (and this defines what is meant by $\nabla f(x)$). Then $$\frac{f(x + hv) - f(x)}{h|v|} = \frac{v\cdot \nabla f(x)}{|v|} + o(1)$$ and the result follows.

Comment: got it, thanks!